# Convert ASCII in a byte array to string

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I seem to be having problems with my string conversions in C#.
My application has received a byte array consisting of an ASCII string (one byte per character). Unfortunately it also has a 0 in the first location. So how do I convert this byte array to a c# string? 
Below is a sample of the data I am trying to convert:

```
byte[] exampleByteArray = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x52, 0x50, 0x4D, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x32, 0x35, 0x35, 0x2C, 0x36, 0x30, 0x0A, 0x00 };
string myString = null;
```

I have made several unsuccessful attempts, so thought I would ask for assistance.
Eventually I need to add the string to a listbox:

```
listBox.Items.Add(myString);
```

The desired output in the listBox: "RPM = 255,630" (with or without the linefeed). 
The byte array will be variable length, but will always be terminated with 0x00

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
byte[] exampleByteArray = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x52, 0x50, 0x4D, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x32, 0x35, 0x35, 0x2C, 0x36, 0x30, 0x0A, 0x00 };
exampleByteArray = exampleByteArray.Where(x=>x!=0x00).ToArray(); // not sure this is OK with your requirements 
string myString =  System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(exampleByteArray).Trim();
```

Result :

> RPM = 255,60

you can add this to `listBox`

```
listBox.Items.Add(myString);
```

Update :

As per new comment  *byte array can contain garbage after the trailing 0x00 (remnants of previous strings).*

You need to skip first `0x00` and then consider bytes until you get `0x00`, so you can use power of Linq to do this task. e.g `ASCII.GetString(exampleByteArray.Skip(1).TakeWhile(x => x != 0x00).ToArray())`

Comment: Oh, so close! I forgot to mention that the byte array can contain garbage after the trailing 0x00 (remnants of previous strings)...

Comment: This sure beats a for loop, THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

```
 byte[] exampleByteArray = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x52, 0x50, 0x4D, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x32, 0x35, 0x35, 0x2C, 0x36, 0x30, 0x0A, 0x00 };
 string myString = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(exampleByteArray);
```

Result: `myString = "\0RPM = 255,60\n\0"`

Answer (score 0):

```
var buffer = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x52, 0x50, 0x4D, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x32, 0x35, 0x35, 0x2C, 0x36, 0x30, 0x0A, 0x00 }
    .Skip(1)
    .TakeWhile(b => b != 0x00).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
```