# Can I initialize string[] or list<string> in managedCuda?

Tags: c#, cuda, string-matching, managed-cuda

I want to use a string matching in managedCuda. But how can I initialized it?

i've tried using C# version, here's the examples:

```
stringAr = new List<string>();
        stringAr.Add("you");
        stringAr.Add("your");
        stringAr.Add("he");
        stringAr.Add("she");
        stringAr.Add("shes");
```

for the string matching, i've used this code:

```
bool found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < stringAr.Count; i++)
        {
            found = (stringAr[i]).IndexOf(textBox2.Text) > -1;
            if (found) break;
        }
        if (found && textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            label1.Text = "Found!";
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "Not Found!";
        }
```

I also allocate input h_A in host memory

```
            string[] h_B = new string[N];
```

When i want to allocate in device memory and copy vectors from host memory to device memory

```
        CudaDeviceVariable<string[]> d_B = h_B;
```

It gave me this error

```
The type 'string[]' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'CudaDeviceVariable<T>'
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/kunzmi/managedCuda/wiki/CudaDeviceVariable) and your error message, only non-nullable value type can be used with `CudaDeviceVariable`.

Change `stringAr` list to a `char[]` (or `byte[]`) array, and then allocate it on device by using `CudaDeviceVariable` with generic parameter char (or byte).

**EDIT1**
Here is the code that change `stringAr` to `byte[]` array:

```
byte[] stringArAsBytes = stringAr
                .SelectMany(s => System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s))
                .ToArray();
```

then try something like this:

```
CudaDeviceVariable<byte> d_data = stringArAsBytes;
```

Comment: Caution, char is not a blittable type in .net: It's representation in managed and unmanaged memory is not the same. So convert you string to byte[] to be on the safe side.

Comment: @kunzmi how to convert on safe side? can you show me some example?

Comment: @Slawomir Orlowski i've tried it, but it got same result.. how can i allocate it with generic parameter? got any example?

Comment: @Slawomir Orlowski Thanks mate :) works like charm.. if i want to return it to string, how can i do it?

Comment: @ThomasYap You're welcome :) I'm not very familiar with managedCuda. If you can access device buffer `d_data` directly, then try this: `string s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(d_data, 0, d_data.Length);`. I'm not quite sure if `d_data.Length` is a proper way to obtain length of `d_data`. Replace it if necessary.

Comment: @SlawomirOrlowski thankyou very much.. But i found thread that discuss about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627304/convert-ascii-in-a-byte-array-to-string). Hope it can be reference to everyone. :)